# I live in an area with a company that claims they've made soft carbonated drink out of lactic acid and milk, how true is it?

Tags: food-chemistry

I live in Iran, recently a massive cooperate company has produced a soda/carbonated soft drink,  under the brand name "luckydo" which they claim it's beneficial for your health and each 2 glasses equal the 1 glass of milk in terms of calcium, I've searched the whole internet there are no products similar to this at all. 
I quote, this is how they claim they've made the product

*"Luckydo is a soda (carbonated soft drink) based on milk!, Fresh milk enters our factory, proteins and fat are separated and all that remains is a liquid that contains calcium, nutrients and vitamins available in the milk's liquid are then combined with different flavors, lactic acid product of fermented milk and water are then added, and alas it's carbonated."*

Here is the picture of the product. 
[image]

- My question is that, is this true?
- if so why no other company on earth has tried or claimed to have such
  product ?
- is it really good for health ?

because I plan on buying lots of these, if what they say is not fake for commercial purposes and true.

Comment: There's something called whey: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whey .In some countries yoghurt-like drinks are sold in a bottle. But this doesn't look or sound like whey or yoghurt. For one thing it's translucent. This sounds like soda pop + calcium + other additives. Impossible to tell from the information provided if it's good for you. Probably not. Best to consult a dietitian. Also, you may want to try the cooking SE site.

Comment: Whey Is very different to yoghurt drinks. If purified(getting rid of whey proteins) their is mainly just lactose(or residuum of it if processed by fermentation as sour whey), lactic acid, salts and other  soluble compounds. It is usually considered healthy, but not frequently directly used.

Comment: How does it taste / feel?  Might answer question w

Comment: Nothing impossible anyway. They recycle waterly part of milk. The fact they claim health benefits is quite common in advertising.  Likely a mere claim but this does not necessarily makes the product unhealthy itself.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it's pretty much like soda, tastes like soda and looks crystal clear. ofc not impossible but then if it is as they claim why no other company on earth has tried to make this "healthy" soda before ? it's just hard to believe there is clacium in that thing.